# Modify value on jsp c:set tag with jquery

Tags: jquery, jsp, jstl, el

I've never worked with jsp, but i have to modify the value on `c:set` tag.

Here is the code:

```
<form id="consultaNuevoCliente" class="form-horizontal form-bordered" 
         role="form" method="POST" action="saveNewClient">

  <div class="form-group">

  <c:set var="client" scope="request" value="${clientService.getClient()}"/>

  <label for="name" class="col-sm-5 
          control-label no-padding-right">Razón Social</label>
  <div class="col-sm-7">

  <input type="text" class="form-control" 
      id="name" name="name" value="${client.getName()}" disabled="disabled">
     </div>

</form>
```

and below the jquery:

```
$(document).on("click", ".infoIcon", function() {
        var clientId = $(this).data('id');//I capture this val to use as parameter in the value="${clientService.getClient(here!);
    });
```

but I cant modify the value of it, I don't know how to put the clientId value on the

```
value="${clientService.getClient(HERE)
```

Comment: You are using a class called `.infoIcon` in your jQuery, but I cannot see it in you HTML code.

Comment: this class is from a button that its created by a pluggin, it works but the thing its that i want to modify the value of the jsp tag with jquery to pass the value of and variable.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are doing it wrong, you are trying to combine jquery with JSP, it means client side data with server side data. you must get first the data from your client|server. and then share it with AJAX (or i would do so) this way you can get any data and put the data in background transparent for the user. make a servlet in java, they are pretty easy to use. then use an AJAX request to get to the servlet, when you get the data just get it using the request.getParameter(""), process and print it, netbeans can help doing a servlet. with this ajax request you can get to your servlet and do the print of the results. to handle `dataType: 'json'` you must use gson or jackson to print a JSON string, or just change for `dataType: 'text'` and you will get the print as is.

```
                $.ajax({
                    cache: false,
                    url: '/pathTOservlet/NewServlet',
                    data: {
                        funcion: 'data_insert'
                    },
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (json, status, xhr) {
                       //DO SOMETHING WITH RESPONSE json
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log(jqXHR);
                        console.log(textStatus);
                        console.log(errorThrown);
                    }
                });
```